# JQuery range form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm Trying to add the below form rulset - range between 1 to 5.

Receiving the following error:

> 'unexpected token ['

range is an array so I'm not really understanding this error.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".formValidation").validate({
        rules:{
            numberRange:{
                required:true,
                range[1,5]
            }
        }
    });
});


<form class = "formValidation">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal information:</legend>
        <p>First name: </p>
        <input type="text" name ="firstName" placeholder = "First name: ">

        <p>Last name: </p>
        <input type="text" name = "lastName" placeholder = "Last name: ">

        <p>A number between 1-5: </p>
        <input type="number" name = "numberRange" placeholder = "Number 1-5: " required>
        <br>
        <br>

        <input type="submit" value = "Submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: you're forgetting a colon: `range: [1,5]`

Comment: Well, I feel stupid. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Expected `:` to define the range it should be like

```
$(".formValidation").validate({
    rules:{
        numberRange:{
            required:true,
            range:[1,5]
        }
    }
});
```